# Problema de alinhamento em CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Tenho a seguinte navbar:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que como podem ver a div#resultados está desalinhada com o input#pesquisa.
Código:

```
<div class="container-fluid primary-bgcolor p-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                <a class="text-white mb-0">
                    <span class="ml-2 d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-none">Nome do Site</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="width: 100%;">
                <input class="form-control primary-fontcolor" type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                <div id="resultados" class="primary-bgcolor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como posso resolver este problema de CSS?

Comment: tentou usar `margin-top`?

Comment: desalinhada em que sentido? Maior?

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com desalinhado? O que vc quer alterar?

Comment: Com desalinhado quero dizer a largura da div#resultados em relação à input, queria que ambas tivessem a mesma largura, porém mesmo setando um width para o elemento pai e para os filhos eles não respeitam esta nova configuração.

Comment: O resultado que eu esperava era algo parecido com o usado em datalist, porém o uso desta tag não se aplica ao meu caso, já que ao usuário clicar no resultado ele será redirecionado por um link

Comment: Cara já que o problema é com o CSS edite sua pergunta e inclua o CSS também

Comment: O CSS que estou utilizando é exatamente o que está no atributo style dentro das tags, fiz isso justamente para melhorar a visualização do código

Comment: Pessoal, o resultado que eu quero alcançar é exatamente o utilizado no Youtube, ao escrever algo é dado os resultado embaixo do input de pesquisa e, justamente, do mesmo tamanho dele e que ao clicar em algum deles o usuário é redirecionado para outra página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque no `input` `id="pesquisa"`:

```
onfocus="this.nextElementSibling.style.width = this.offsetWidth+'px'"
```

Desta forma ao focar no `input` irá ajustar a largura da `div #resultados` à mesma largura do `input`.

**Exemplo:**

```css
#resultados{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid primary-bgcolor p-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                <a class="text-white mb-0">
                    <span class="ml-2 d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-none">Nome do Site</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="width: 100%;">
                <input onfocus="this.nextElementSibling.style.width = this.offsetWidth+'px'" class="form-control primary-fontcolor" type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                <div id="resultados" class="primary-bgcolor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">abc</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vi que você está usando bootstrap
Você quer deixar a div embaixo na mesma posição do input?
Caso seja isso tire esse position e coloca col-12 na div.
Caso queira input ao lado de div, coloca col-6 no input e col-6 na div.

```
<div class="container-fluid primary-bgcolor p-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                <a class="text-white mb-0">
                    <span class="ml-2 d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-none">Nome do Site</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="width: 100%;">
                <input class="form-control primary-fontcolor" type="text" name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                <div id="resultados" class="col-12 primary-bgcolor" style=" z-index: 2; width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; background:#c0c0c0;">Teste</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gabriela, esta modificação não resolveu o problema, apesar da div#resultados aparecer do mesmo tamanho do input#pesquisa, ao aparecer ela toma espaço na navbar alargando-a

Comment: Gabriela, o que estou tentando realizar é o tipo de pesquisa utilizado no Youtube, por exemplo, eu preciso que ao clicar em um dos resultados o usuário seja redirecionado